# Pass stored procedure result to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Quick question that I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed with an array issue.

Basically I have a stored procedure that outputs some course categories and I want to pass all of the rows to an array.

```
Subject            SubjectCode

Applied Science    F04
Access to HE       F05
```

So basically the above is an example of what I get from the stored procedure and I'd like to pass the results of the subject to an array.

```
Dim num as Integer
Dim strNumResult as String

num = 0

Do While (rsData.Read())

num = num + 1

strNumResult = num.ToString()

Dim array(strNumResult) as String

loop
```

I'm assuming that I'd need to count the amount of rows in the procedure first, then put this result into the array? How would I then systematically pull all subjects in the procedure into the array?

Thanks!

Comment: Added the points where I'm up to - just not sure on how to proceed to actually output the results into the array.

Comment: General point: do not declare variables before their first use, and initialise them in the declaration. This makes the code shorter, easier to follow (data flow is more explicit) and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a `List(Of Subject)` instead which can be resized. I would also create a class for the subject since you have two fields.

```
Dim subjects = New List(Of Subject)
Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Try
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read
                    Dim subject = reader.GetString(0)
                    Dim subjectCode = reader.GetString(1)
                    subjects.Add(New Subject() With {
                                 .Subject = subject,
                                 .SubjectCode = subjectCode
                             })
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' log exception 
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

here's a simple implementation of that class:

```
Public Class Subject
    Public Subject As String
    Public SubjectCode As String
End Class
```

If you insist on an array, you can call `subjects.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `GetRows` method which will get your recordset data into an array:

```
array = recordset.GetRows(Rows, Start, Fields )
```

Basically execute your stored procedure and when you have the results use the GetRows method which returns a collection of rows from the result, given an array of unique column ID's.

You can see an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In your case after making sure that you have some records returned you can do this:

```
arrData = rsData.GetRows()
```

Hope this helps.